# Conversion in Point Cloud Library from proprietary format to float; no matching function found

Tags: c++, templates, type-conversion, point-clouds, point-cloud-library

I have what I think is a fairly basic question about a conversion in the [point cloud library](http://www.pointclouds.org) from a proprietry data type to float. My issue I think comes from a lack of experience with templates, data types and C++ in general.

The function that should perform this conversion is [copyToFloatArray](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.0.1/classpcl_1_1_default_point_representation_3_01_f_p_f_h_signature33_01_4.html#aae8d2a0cb1e0e55a1c33f9dcc63492cf), defined in the documentation as:

> virtual void pcl::DefaultPointRepresentation< FPFHSignature33 >::copyToFloatArray (   const FPFHSignature33 &     p,
>   float *     out
>   )            const [inline, virtual]
>
> Copy point data from input point to a float array.
>
> This method must be overriden in all subclasses.
>
> Parameters:
>
> p     The input point
>
> out   A pointer to a float array.
>
> Implements pcl::PointRepresentation< FPFHSignature33 >.

I have attempted to implement it as follows:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::FPFHSignature33>::Ptr fpfhs (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::FPFHSignature33> ());
// populate fpfh...
float **myArray;
pcl::DefaultPointRepresentation< pcl::FPFHSignature33 >::copyToFloatArray ( &fpfhs, &**myArray);
```

The error that's thrown up at compilation time is as follows:

```
/home/bc/PCL/pcd_read.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/home/bc/PCL/pcd_read.cpp:68: error: no matching function for call to 
‘pcl::DefaultPointRepresentation<pcl::FPFHSignature33>::copyToFloatArray(boost::shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::FPFHSignature33> >*, float*)’
/usr/include/pcl-1.2/pcl/point_representation.h:254: note: candidates are: 
virtual void pcl::DefaultPointRepresentation<pcl::FPFHSignature33>::copyToFloatArray(const pcl::FPFHSignature33&, float*) const
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/pcd_read.dir/pcd_read.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/pcd_read.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

It appears that the issue is in the first argument being passed to the function, but I can't seem to create a `const FPFHSignature33 & p` object.

Does anyone have any idea if these suspicions are correct, and if so what direction I might take to start to resolve the issue?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to allocate memory in your floatArray.
Then, you need to derefence the fpfhs ptr using *. finally, there is no need for a double pointer array there.

Here is the corrected code :

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::FPFHSignature33>::Ptr fpfhs (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::FPFHSignature33> ());
// populate fpfh...
float *myArray = new float[ 3* point_count ];
pcl::DefaultPointRepresentation< pcl::FPFHSignature33 >::copyToFloatArray ( *fpfhs, myArray);
```